# Can't remove the heatsinks on a MacPro 3,1 (earily 2008), even though I have the screws out?

Tags: mac-pro, cpu

I have a MacPro 3,1 and the screen keeps going black and the fan starts blowing at high speed.

I ruled out that it was my OS by running Clonezilla and attempting to clone the harddrive, and during the clone it eventually exhibited the same symptoms.

I was able to clone the hard drive on another machine with no issue.

I also plugged in, only a single stick of ram while trying to clone the hard drive and got the same results, so that leaves the logic board, the PSU and the CPUs.

I'm attempting to go the CPU route, but I can't get the heatsinks off to repaste them.

I've unscrewed all 4 screws on the heatsink for CPU A and I still can't lift it off the CPU, I hear alot of creaking down there, but it still won't lift off.

Comment: Is [this](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/faq/mac-pro-how-to-upgrade-processors.html) any help?

Comment: You might want to look at an actual [Apple Mac Pro early 2008 service manual](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/macpro/macpro_early2008.pdf).

Comment: Did you first test it was actually overheating? Otherwise it seems a bit of a leap to just assume it's the thermal paste, before at least running AHT, changing the PRAM battery, testing the memory risers separately, using a different set of SATA sockets & cables, swapping out the GPU, etc, etc...

Comment: What's AHT?  (Apple Hardware Test?)  What's a PRAM battery?  Is that the battery on the motherboard?